# StackGrid WPF designer issue

Tags: catel

When I use catels StackGrid the designer shows all content in the first cell.
After compiling the project the grid is rendered fine within the designer.
Is there any other way forcing the wpf designer to update without recompiling?

Comment: I am afraid not. I never recommend to use the designer anyway (typing xaml is just faster and you get exactly what you want). You can look into fixing it, but it has to be a PR then. If you want to, you can create an issue in the official issue tracker: http://www.catelproject.com/support/issue-tracker/

Comment: I do not use the designer to actually design the content. But it is really useful to see what you type in XAML. And this does not happen for the StackGrid without recompile sometimes.